# How to handle Multiple check-boxes in Reactjs?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox

"I am really stuck in this problem for past 1 week. Actually I am getting an array of strings from the API that contains the ID of employees. Now I am showing it in a table and it contains check-boxes before them. Now when I sort the Admin ID column, the Admins get sorted out but the check-boxes are left in there original position."

So I want a solution where both the Admin ID and check-boxes move simultaneously with each other on sorting that column.

I will attach some screenshots of the table so that it will be easy to understand the problem"

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first Screenshot is before sorting the column and the second one is after the sorting.

Comment: Can you please show us some relevant code to this? It's hard to answer without seeing how you're currently handling the checkboxes